# Hibernate Validation @NotBlank trim issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

@NotBlank is used to handle Null values and to perform Trim. Now consider the below code,

```
Class ABC{

   @NotBlank
   @Size(min=3, max=5)
   private String name;

}
```

Here the name should have a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 5.

Now if I am passing the name as "ab " , here trimming doesn’t take place automatically and the validator takes it as valid input. Why is that so? How to use Annotation to solve this issue, rather than writing a function to check it?

Comment: Validation annotations are supposed to validate the input, not change them. What you are trying to achieve seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add @Pattern constraint with regex to exclude blanks

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own custom validator. As explained in the following link create new interface and implementation class. In the isValid() method write your own validation mechanism.

[Spring MVC Custom Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)